# Execute a function randomly

Tags: python, function, random

Consider the following functions:

```
def a():
    print "a"
def b():
    print "b"
```

Is there a way to pick a function to run randomly? I tried using:

```
random.choice([a(),b()])
```

but it returns both functions, I just want it to return one function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only call the *selected* function, not both of them:

```
random.choice([a,b])()
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> import random
>>> def a():
...     print "a"
...
>>> def b():
...     print "b"
...
>>> random.choice([a,b])()
a
>>> random.choice([a,b])()
b
>>>
```

Your old code called *both* functions when the list `[a(),b()]` was created, causing Python to print both `a` and `b`.  Afterwards, it told `random.choice` to choose from the list `[None, None]`<sup>1</sup>, which does nothing.  You can see this from the demonstration below:

```
>>> [a(),b()]
a
b
[None, None]
>>>
```

The new code however uses `random.choice` to randomly select a function object from the list `[a,b]`:

```
>>> random.choice([a,b])
<function b at 0x01AFD970>
>>> random.choice([a,b])
<function a at 0x01AFD930>
>>>
```

It then calls only that function.

---

<sup>1</sup>Functions return `None` by default.  Since `a` and `b` lack return-statements, they each return `None`.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that, works marvelously, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

`random.choice([a,b])()`