# My code is running without calling variable in Python?

Tags: python

When I run the below code my websites or steam still open. Shouldn't I need to state `print(link)` or `print(steam)` for them to open?

```
import os
import webbrowser
import subprocess
import random

urls = ['https://www.ft.com/', 
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvqcFcfhUVQ',
        'https://roadmap.sh/backend',
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYXdXT2l-Gg&list=PL-osiE80TeTskrapNbzXhwoFUiLCjGgY7']

foxpath = 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/Firefox.exe %s'

link = webbrowser.get(foxpath).open(random.choice(urls))
steam = subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe'])
```

Why does this happen?

I eventually want to run the program from a function call, like below.

```
def wildcard():

    print(random.choice(link, steam))

wildcard()
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "calling a variable". You call *functions*.

Comment: Whats not making sense......your code says thins like webbrowser.get.open. this does just waht it says it will open the broswer and what your storing in link is the result of opening that website. same with steam. subprocess.call will call steam and you will store the result of opening steam in a variable called steam.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you issue `webbrowser.get` or `subprocess.call`, they execute. Your variables are really storing the return values of those functions, not aliases to those function calls.

If you want to alias the function calls as it appears you are intending, you could do something like this:

```
def open_link():
    return webbrowser.get(foxpath).open(random.choice(urls))

def open_steam():
    return subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe'])
```

Then your top level would be:

```
def wildcard():
     random.choice([link, steam])()

wildcard()
```

Note the syntax difference for choosing the functions randomly. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640169/execute-a-function-randomly) answer for more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing special about `print`. `print` is just a function that takes in some value and displays it to the user.

If you had instead `steam = 3 * 4`, would you be surprised to learn that the value `12` is computed, and `steam` becomes a name for that value, even if you don't do anything with it? It's the same thing here - calling `subprocess.call` causes the program to launch, and it has nothing to do with the name `steam`, nor anything that you do or don't do with that name subsequently.

If you were to add the `print(steam)` line that you have in mind, what it would display (after you close steam and control returns to your program) is the "return code" of that program - this gets into the details of how your operating system works, but most likely it would be something like `0`.

If you want something that you can later call in order to launch Steam - well, that's a *function*. Like you already know how to do:

```
def steam():
    subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You do invoke something:

```
steam = subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe'])
```

The documentation for `subprocess.call` is clear on what the `call` method does: it invokes the given argument as a subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code isn't inside a function, so, when you execute it, it runs all the diretives including 
`steam = subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe'])`

Which calls `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe`, opening your steam app.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, I understand now. I actually just resolved the problem with the following

```
def wildcard():
    for x in range(1):
        rand = random.randint(1, 10)
        if rand > 5:
            link = webbrowser.get(foxpath).open(random.choice(urls))
        else:
            subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe'])


wildcard()
```